# Cast const member function to non-const

Tags: c++, casting, constants

Is casting the `const`ness of member function pointers defined in C++? Is the following valid code?

```
struct T {
  void foo(int i) const { std::cout << i << std::endl;};
};

void (T::*f1)(int) const = &T::foo;
void (T::*f2)(int)       = reinterpret_cast<void (T::*)(int)>(f1);
T t;
(t.*f2)(1);
```

**Update:**

The reason why I need this is that I'm writing a function that accepts both an object and a member function pointer to that object. I need a version for const objects (accepting only const functions) and a normal one. Since I don't want duplicate code, my idea was to put the actual code in the non-const version and call it from the const one, casting away any consts.

Comment: even if it is defined you shouldnt do it. const variables are const for a reason

Comment: @Gir Well, not quite that easy. Casting away const-ness on a variable basically tries to _add writability_ (ie raise expectations), while casting away const-ness on this method tries to _relieve the function from having to give the "I won't change internal state" guarantee_ (ie lower expectations).

Comment: @Gir but these are not variables. You seem not to be understanding what the `const` keyword means when applied to functions.

Comment: But it won't change behavior of the function, what do you need this for??

Comment: @klm123: It won't change anything. const is a syntactic sugar for c++ programs, unless you are using it like "static const int i = 1;". that may be optimized out, unless you write "&i" somewhere, in witch case it won't. it's even more true for functions. You can't pass anything to a function witch will be optimized out, so you can blatantly cast away and back any const inside or outside the function.

Comment: See the updated question, I've added a quick explanation.

Comment: If you give examples of these functions and how do you use them the discussion will be more convenient

Comment: The standard does not guarantee this will work for `reinterpret_cast<>()` bestter to use `const_cast<>()` to cast away constness.

Comment: `const_cast` did not work in this case.

Comment: @lucasclemente: Then I am doubly sure what you are doing is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiler eats it.
But the backward cast is more useful.

And again but - it is better to don't use it, const_cast is usually just a quick and dirty solution, which you apply only when there are not any other solution.

**Answer to update**

If I understand you correctly you are going to use one object and two function. First function accepts const object and const member-function, second - non-const object and non-const member-function.

According to given information you can change second function to accept non-const object and const member-function. And give them one non-const object and its const member-function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is defined, but you maybe don't want it if the function is really const, because some compiler optimizations (namely return value caching) depend on the function being const.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but it has no meaning, wherever you can call f2, you can also call f1 too. You should cast in the other way. But if something, you should cast the object, not the function.

```
void (T::*f1)(int) const = &T::foo;
void (T::*f2)(int)       = reinterpret_cast<void (T::*)(int)>(f1);
T t;
(t.*f2)(1); // compiles
(t.*f1)(1); // this compiles too!!
```

but if you have

```
const T t;
(t.*f2)(1); // error t is const
(t.*f1)(1); // still compiles
```

Answer (score 0):

The only was to resolve the ambiguity is to perform a static_cast, this is basically a language feature

```
#include <boost/typeof/typeof.hpp>
struct Test
{
    const int& foo();
    const int& foo() const;
};

int main()
{
    typedef const int&(Test::*non_const_ptr)();
    typedef const int&(Test::*const_ptr)()const;
    BOOST_TYPEOF(static_cast<non_const_ptr>(&Test::foo)) ss;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't see a reason for doing this: even if you could, you'd make it more restrictive.
Let's say you have a class Foo:

```
class Foo {
  void f() const;
  void g();
}
```

And some snippet of code:

```
Foo a;
const Foo b;
```

Then you can call both `a.f()` and `a.g()`, but not `b.g()` because `b` is `const`. As you can see, placing `const` after a member function makes it less restrictive, not more.

And, by `reinterpret_cast`ing this pointer, you'll get the pointer with exact same value(due to the nature of `reinterpret_cast`), and if you try to call it, you'll get into the same T::foo()